# Physical exercise or weight training for Burning extra fats on cheek,neck and belly?

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, gym, body-fat

I am 172 cm and 76 kg.
I have a little bit fat on cheek,neck and belly.

I am working-out in gym from past 4 months.
I have good result with my body muscles(Biceps,Chest,Shoulder,back,legs)
But I think not with parts from question.

So my question is do we need to do lot of cardio and physical exercise like plank on floor,alternate leg raises,rope skipping to for fat loss?
And does this exercises has any effect on muscles and size of chest,biceps,shoulder?

Comment: this is on diet

Comment: This type of question has been asked many times before.  You **cannot** spot reduce fat from one particular area on your body.  A consistent exercise program and calorie restriction (monitoring) will help burn fat from your entire body.

Comment: @rrirower please comment link i am unable to find

Comment: The body parts are different, but, the concept is the same [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25042/lower-body-fat-problem/25043#25043), [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16231/i-am-5-ft-6-and-56-kilos-best-work-out-routine-for-me-to-get-a-flat-stomach/16240#16240), and [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9581/are-ab-exercises-more-usefull-to-reduce-belly-fat-than-other-exercises/9589#9589) to name a few.  If you search "spot reduce", you'll find many more.

Comment: @rrirower - You provide 3 links, one of which is closed as a dupe of a 4th question, and no vote to close? :p

Comment: @JohnP Brain fart....

Comment: @rrirower - Hah! :) I get those a lot.

Answer (score -1):

When you say "workout" I'm assuming lifting weights because you were talking about your muscles. Although lifting does help your metabolism, it doesn't really help you lose weight if you don't add cardio workouts to your workout routine. As in some of the previous comments, you can't really reduce access fat in specific areas of the body. Rather you lose % body fat throughout your **entire** body. Lifting is nice and all, but try to add some running, biking, or some other form of cardio into your workout. You might want to try to run 1+ miles before or after you lift weights. This will get your blood pumping and will help you lose that extra fat. If you only lift, it'll just add muscle to your body underneath all that fat. Running, swimming, biking, etc. can help your cardiovascular system which in return can help reduce chest paid, heart problems, and you'll notice that your breathing will improve immensely.

Edit: I was speaking from experience. My chest would always feel uncomfortable and I would have a lot of chest pain. And I got rid of my belly by running...slowly coming back though so I gotta hit those treadmills! Good luck!

Comment: -1. While you may not lose weight, since it weighs more than fat, building muscle is one of the best fat burners out there since muscle uses more calories to maintain itself than fat. Also, it doesn't matter the type of exercise, you lose fat in a specific order. The last place gained is the first place lost. The specific sites differ from person to person.